# 403 Error on Microsoft Graph API - Retrieve an online meeting by joinWebUrl

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a python script that successfully makes a number of Graph API calls to retreive various Teams details, like subscribing to chats, getting the meeting url from the chat etc.

There is a step in the flow of API calls I need to make that is consistently giving a 403 forbidden error.

**The API Endpoint I am trying to hit is [GET /v1.0/users/onlinemeeting/joinweburl](https://GET%20https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/dc17674c-81d9-4adb-bfb2-8f6a442e4622/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20%27https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fl%2Fmeetup-join%2F19%253ameeting_MGQ4MDQyNTEtNTQ2NS00YjQxLTlkM2EtZWVkODYxODYzMmY2%2540thread.v2%2F0%3Fcontext%3D%257b%2522Tid%2522%253a%2522909c6581-5130-43e9-88f3-fcb3582cde37%2522%252c%2522Oid%2522%253a%2522dc17674c-81d9-4adb-bfb2-8f6a442e4622%2522%257d%27)**

Here is my python code that gets a token and executes the request:

```
def get_token2():
    # Get the token
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("login.microsoftonline.com")

    payload = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'client_id': 'REDACTED',
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'client_secret': 'REDACTED',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    })

    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

    conn.request("POST", "/REDACTED/oauth2/v2.0/token", payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()

    token2 = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))['access_token']

    return token2
    
    def get_online_meetings(joinWebUrl, token2):
    print(f"joinWebUrl for the second API call: {joinWebUrl}")

    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/REDACTED/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'{joinWebUrl}'"
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    req.add_header('Authorization', f'Bearer {token2}')
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
            data = response.read()
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            print("Meeting ID: ", json_data["value"][0]["id"])
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {err}")
    except urllib.error.URLError as err:
        print(f"URL error occurred: {err}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    def main():
    chat_id = input("Enter chat ID: ")
    token = get_token()  # Retrieve the token
    joinWebUrl = get_chat(chat_id, token)
    new_token = get_token2()  # Retrieve a new token
    print(new_token)
    get_online_meetings(joinWebUrl, new_token)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I have verified that the registered app I am using has the appropriate permissions at the application, not delegate level. Verified here by checking `token2` in jwt

[image: Screenshot of JWT.ms output when I inspect the contents of new_token generated by getToken2]

I feel as if I have tried everything

An additional interesting point, is that I even get a 403 when making this call with the `me` endpoint (user delegated authentication) and I am running as the Azure and Teams owner account.

### Background on Code

I did not include my full python code, but it is a simple script just for testing out APIs that:

1. gets a token
2. gets chat entity from chat ID (user manually types in)
3. gets a new token
4. uses joinWebURL from step 2 to get organizer ID (this is the API call that fails)

Has anyone ever encountered this issue where a 403 is given even though the application has all of the required permissions and Admin Consent granted?

Comment: If you try accessing the endpoint through the Graph Explorer, does it work or do you get the same errors?

Comment: I get the same errors on the explorer. I've tried on the explorer both using app permission, and with a signed in user delegated auth which is the owner of the azure subscription.

Comment: Is this the only API not working, or you get 403 for any API call?

Comment: Btw probably "roles" in the token is something else, shouldn't the permissions be listed in "scopes", i.e. in the "scp" field? As far as I remember, that was the case (unless something changed)?

Answer (score 0):

Are the contents of your joinWebUrl variable URL Encoded? Or a standard URL?

Checking [Get onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API documentation, in the Notes section it states "**joinWebUrl must be URL encoded.**" From Example #3 further down in the docs:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq 'https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fl%2Fmeetup-join%2F19%253ameeting_MGQ4MDQyNTEtNTQ2NS00YjQxLTlkM2EtZWVkODYxODYzMmY2%2540thread.v2%2F0%3Fcontext%3D%257b%2522Tid%2522%253a%2522909c6581-5130-43e9-88f3-fcb3582cde37%2522%252c%2522Oid%2522%253a%2522dc17674c-81d9-4adb-bfb2-8f6a442e4622%2522%257d'
```

Does joinWebUrl varible look like this?

```
https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fl%2Fmeetup-join%2F19%253ameeting_[TRUNCATED]
```

or this

```
https://teams.microsoft.com[TRUNCATED]
```